# A script on JSP page to check for values in database

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans java.

I have a 2 factor authentication for my login, password and a verification code send by mail. I have assigned an integer value to the user row once he has verified.

However, I need a verifystatus check for every JSP page to make sure that he did not bypass the 2nd factor authentication and access JSP pages by typing in the URL manually.

For now my JSP can be accessed once he is logged in without passing through the 2nd authentication, and I want to make sure that the logged in user is authenticated twice before he can access any JSP pages.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can use user session - `HTTPSession`. After the user logs in by verifying the password, set a session attribute `factor_variable`. After the 2nd factor authentication, set some value to this session variable. And before loading any JSP page, check if this session variable `factor_variable` is **NOT** `null`.

1. If the user has passed the 2nd factor authentication, then this `factor_variable` is not `null`.

2. If the `factor_variable` is `null`, then the user has bypassed the 2nd factor authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have three options:

1. Query the database on every page load to check that the 'verified' flag is 1. Not very efficient.
2. Store the 'verified' flag in the session cookie. This is relatively easy to 'hack' in case someone really wants to, as the values are stored in plain text. You can of course encrypt the value for better security.
3. Wrap all the user info inside a java object, including the 'verified' flag. Populate and store the object in the session on login. Query the object from the session on each page load and check the flag there. Most efficient way.